# SFTPGo with nginx-ingress controller on GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, sftp, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, google-vpc

I am trying to deploy SFTPGo with nginx-ingress controller on GKE. The deployment works but when I try to build sftp connection through cli, it fails with connection refused/timed out error.

I am using drakkan/sftpgo helm chart for SFTPGo deployment. Adding deployment, service and ingress yamls below:

```
# Source: sftpgo/templates/service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: release-name-sftpgo
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: sftpgo-0.19.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: sftpgo
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.5.4"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
    beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "hc-test"}'
    cloud.google.com/l4-rbs: enabled
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: sftp
      port: 22
      targetPort: sftp
      protocol: TCP
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
    - name: telemetry
      port: 10000
      targetPort: telemetry
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: sftpgo
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
---
```

```
# Source: sftpgo/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: release-name-sftpgo
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: sftpgo-0.19.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: sftpgo
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.5.4"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: sftpgo
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: sftpgo
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: sftpgo
      hostNetwork: false
      securityContext:
        {}
      containers:
        - name: sftpgo
          securityContext:
            {}
          image: "ghcr.io/drakkan/sftpgo:v2.5.4"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          args:
            - sftpgo
            - serve
          env:
            - name: SFTPGO_SFTPD__BINDINGS__0__PORT
              value: "2022"
            - name: SFTPGO_SFTPD__BINDINGS__0__ADDRESS
              value: "0.0.0.0"
            - name: SFTPGO_HTTPD__BINDINGS__0__PORT
              value: "8080"
            - name: SFTPGO_HTTPD__BINDINGS__0__ADDRESS
              value: "0.0.0.0"
            - name: SFTPGO_TELEMETRY__BIND_PORT
              value: "10000"
            - name: SFTPGO_TELEMETRY__BIND_ADDRESS
              value: "0.0.0.0"
          ports:
            - name: sftp
              containerPort: 2022
              protocol: TCP
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
            - name: telemetry
              containerPort: 10000
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: telemetry
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: telemetry
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          resources:
            {}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config
              mountPath: /etc/sftpgo/sftpgo.json
              subPath: sftpgo.json
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: release-name-sftpgo
---
```

```
# Source: sftpgo/templates/ingress-nginx.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sftpgo-ingress
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: sftpgo-0.19.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: sftpgo
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.5.4"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  namespace: sftpgo
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: "google-managed-cert"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "sftpgo-external"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "sample.domain" #
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: release-name-sftpgo
                port:
                  number: 80
            path: /
            pathType: Prefix
          - backend:
              service:
                name: release-name-sftpgo
                port:
                  number: 22
            path: /
            pathType: Prefix
```

```
# Source: sftpgo/templates/backendconfig.yaml
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: hc-test
spec:
  healthCheck:
    timeoutSec: 1
    type: HTTP
    requestPath: /healthz
    port: 8080
  healthCheck:
    timeoutSec: 1
    type: TCP
    requestPath: /
    port: 2022
```

Also, I'm new to nginx-ingress and I'm unable to figure out how to use managed certs with nginx-ingress on GKE but my major concern is sftp connection unable to build. The sftpgo web page is displayed and exposed properly but the problem lies with sftp connection (ports are added in service and being exposed too)

Answer (score 1):

Ingress only supports HTTP(S) protocols, which is why you are able to access the web page.  To expose other TCP protocols such as sftp, you would typically use a [Service of type LoadBalancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service-load-balancer):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sftpgo-lb-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  app.kubernetes.io/name: sftpgo
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: release-name
  ports:
  - name: tcp-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 22
    targetPort: sftp
```